# What does lowercase 'beta' mean in this graph of radio-emitting galaxies?

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, cosmology, radio-astronomy

[image: X-Y plot from article]

> Correlation between the mass of the galaxies (X-axis) and the difference of their radio emissions at different radio frequencies (Y-axis). Each symbol represents an individual galaxy. The image of an example galaxy is from NASA/ESA Hubble Space Telescope T means the time for light to travel from these galaxies to us.
>
> Credit: Fangxia An (IDIA/UWC)

From [Phys.org](https://phys.org/news/2021-08-analysis-galaxies-meerkat-radio-telescope.html)
and [The Conversation](https://theconversation.com/analysis-of-2-000-galaxies-using-the-meerkat-radio-telescope-reveals-fresh-insights-166353),

> Using the Meerkat Telescope on over 2,000 radio galaxies...

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual url to the webpage in question.

Comment: Surely it's the slope of the line?

Comment: In the article, "our new study" links to [this MNRAS paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2021MNRAS.tmp.2057A/abstract).

Comment: The abstract of that paper confirms @ProfRob’s suggestion — it’s the slope of the relation.

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer that I am writing up based on comments by [ProfRob](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/2531/profrob) and [Mike G](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/616/mike-g).

The meaning of 'beta' in these plots is the slope of the line.  The figure itself is from [Radio spectral properties of star-forming galaxies in the MIGHTEE-COSMOS field and their impact on the far-infrared-radio correlation](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2021MNRAS.507.2643A/abstract) ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.02778)).

From the caption of the figure in the above question:

"The linear fit is performed by minimizing the $\chi^{2}$ and using the uncertainties of $\alpha^{3.0GHz}_{1.3GHz}$ as the inverse weights. The slopes of these linear fits, $\beta$, are given on the right-bottom corner of each panel."

Comment: Which for me, raises another question: what's the point of performing a linear fit, when there's no clear correlation between the x and y variables? What am I missing?